# WSO2 Identity Server - relyingPartyRedirectUrls not working for Chrome or Internet Explorer

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I recently set up WSO2 Identity Server 5.7.0, and users have begun using it extensively.  However, some are running into a problem where they accidentally hit the Back button in their browser after logging in, and they don't know how to get back to the application at that point.  Refreshing the page does nothing, and trying to log in again takes them to an "Authentication Error" message on `<IS_HOME>/repository/deployment/server/webapps/authenticationendpoint/retry.jsp`, which does not provide any links to take them back to the service provider application.

I found this solution in the WSO2 documentation:

https://docs.wso2.com/m/mobile.action#page/85367898/header/CustomizingtheAuthenticationEndpoint-Handlingbrowserbackbuttonandbookmarkedloginpage

I have implemented the `relyingPartyRedirectUrls` resource under `/_system/config/identity/config` in the WSO2 Registry for each of the service provider applications defined in the environment, and it is working exactly as I had hoped in Firefox 68.3 ESR and Edge 44.  However, it does not seem to work for Chrome 79 or Internet Explorer 11.

**Problem script:**
`/logincontext?sessionDataKey=19283828-7f3a-49ff-a640-58b95d252b4d&relyingParty=my-sp-name&tenantDomain=carbon.super`

In Firefox, this script contains the following code in the response:
`{"status":"redirect","redirectUrl":"https://my.sp.com/"}`

However, the same script in Chrome contains this code in the response:
`{"status":"success"}`

Do you have any recommendations for what tweaks I could make to the configuration in order to get this fix working in all (or most) browsers?  If you have other recommendations for ways to mitigate the pain for users who don't think to click the "Forward" button in their browser, I would be very open to hearing them.

P.S. When a user tries to log in a second time after clicking the Back button, this is what shows up in wso2carbon.log:

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2020-01-13 18:52:20,400] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.request.impl.DefaultRequestCoordinator} -  Context does not exist. Probably due to invalidated cache
TID: [-1234] [] [2020-01-13 18:52:20,400]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.request.impl.DefaultRequestCoordinator} -  Authentication context is null, redirect parameter filtering will not be done for 19283828-7f3a-49ff-a640-58b95d252b4d
```

P.P.S. I discovered that when I load a bookmarked URL in Chrome 79, the fix works as expected.  Also, if I use the Back button to get to the login page and then refresh the login page, that also causes the fix to take me into the app.  It is only the initial load of the login page after clicking the Back button where the fix doesn't work (in Chrome 79, at least; the fix doesn't work under any of those circumstances in IE 11).

Comment: Sorry, cannot help you with your issue, but wondering.. why do you use IS 5.7.0 and not the latest stable 5.9.0 which was released few months back? in git i see last update in 5.7.0 on 13 Sep 2018 ..

Comment: I am using a vendor product that is based on IS 5.7.0, so I don't have the freedom to upgrade the version of IS within that product.

Answer (score 0):

I tested the Chrome 79 with the dashboard app with the above configs and it worked fine. Can you check with the dashboard application?

If you want you can create a git issue in https://github.com/wso2/product-is/issues to report this behaviour directly to WSO2 IAM team.

Another suggestion, if you find the retry.jsp not intuitive enough, you can always modify/replace that with your custom implementation. For example if you have one main application, then you can add the link to your homepage in the retry.jsp. Then users can always go back to your application using that link.

Comment: I don't know if it matters or not, but I've tested using Chrome 79.0.3945.117 and 79.0.3945.130, 64-bit in both cases.

Comment: Regarding your suggestion about adding the application link into retry.jsp, unfortunately my IS instance is servicing many different service providers.

Also, because it is a vendor-packaged version of 5.7.0, I don't believe that the dashboard is a part of the install that I have.  I'm not familiar with that part of the product, so I'm not sure where to look for it.